# What is the Correct Method of Admob Banner in Fragments (Updated 2024)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

I have an application where I use Admob ads. I want to show banner ads in different locations within these fragments. But I have some questions in my mind. I would be pleased if you answer.

[please review this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY0YO.png)

> First Question:
> Does there need to be a different AdUnitId for each fragment or should it be the same? For example, how many AdUnitIds should there be for 3 fragments?

> Second Question:
> Where should adViews be created to be displayed in the Fragment? In other words, should it be created within fragments or within the activity to which the fragments depend?

> Third Question:
> Does an AdHelper type structure make sense?

```
public class AdHelper {

    private final Activity activity;
    private AdView adView;

    public AdHelper(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void loadBannerAd(LinearLayout adLayout) {
        adView = new AdView(activity);
        adView.setAdUnitId(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
        adLayout.addView(adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.LARGE_BANNER); //Here you can change the "AdSize"
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```